# How to stop Chromatic diff "noise" with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, storybook, visual-testing, chromatic

When viewing Chromatic as part of our merge requests finding actual meaningful diffs is like finding a needle in a haystack.

Highcharts has their weird variation where the position of parts (e.g. lines) seems to vary ever so slightly.

We've tried Chromatic settings for:

- Tolerances (but that causes issues with missing actual small changes)
- Delays (still didn't work, still seeing variation)

We can conditionally use our Chromatic flag to configure Highcharts if there's a potential solution there but we have no idea what that is.

Other teams at our company have done away with visual diffs entirely due to this issue it's pretty absurd and annoying!